Cannot configure iptables to DROP traffic from everywhere
Given the iptables listing below, could anyone explain me why I'm still able to access from everywhere the service inside a docker container (IP 192.168.160.2:8050) which was supposed to be accessible only to traffic comming from 217.13.124.92? Thanks.
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere      

#other chains ommited for the sake of clarity

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  217.13.124.92        192.168.160.2        tcp dpt:8050
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.160.2        tcp dpt:8050
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere


Please take a comment to read the Docker tag that you added to your question.  Specifically, it states that Docker questions must be software development related.

I don't know how Docker's fake networks are configured.  If 217.13.124.92 is the host and you use NAT, it's possible the source IP really IS 217.13.124.92.
